# AddEventListener únicamente borra el ultimo valor del bucle con botones

Tags: javascript

Estoy buscando la manera de utilizar addEventListener y que me genere el valor deseado enviado por mi fuction(valor). Solo toma el último valor del bucle.

```
 function deleteItem(index){

                cart.splice(index,1);
                showCart();
                saveCart();

            }




         function mostrar_carrito() {


                    $("#cart").css("visibility", "visible");
                    $("#cartBody").empty();

                    for (var i in cart) {

                        var item = cart[i];
                        var row = "<tr><td>" + item.Product + "</td><td>" +
                                     item.Price + "</td><td>" + item.Qty + "</td><td>"
                                     + item.Qty * item.Price + "</td><td id='someArea'>"



            var button = document.createElement("button");
            button.innerHTML = i;
             button.addEventListener("click", function(){ deleteItem(i); });
             + "</td></tr>"


                        $("#someArea").append(button);
                        $("#cartBody").append(row);


                    }
                }
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Fijate que edite mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es un problema (en realidad es un feature) bien conocido como "Clousure dentro de un loop".. y se da cuando declaras una funcion dentro de un loop.

Hay [varias formas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750506/2573335) de solucionarlo. La mas simple es usar `let` en lugar de `var`. El asunto es que las variables declaradas con `var` son globales a la función y debido a esto todos los handlers acaban apuntando al mismo valor (como si de punteros se tratara), es decir que todos los botones apuntan al ultimo valor que tomo la variable `i`. Pero `let` opera diferente y cada iteración del bucle usa una instancia diferente de la variable.

ejemplo:

```
for(let i in cart) { 
  // .. restro del codigo
}
```

Pero si necesitas que funcione en navegadores Legacy, esta opción no servirá pues fue agregada recientemente en ES2015.

En ese caso deberías usar una función externa para cambiar el scope de la variable `i`.

algo asi como

```
for(var i in cart) { 
  otrafuncion(i);
}

// luego fuera del loop, creas la función otraFuncion con el código que ya tenias. 
function otraFuncion(i) {
  // restro del codigo aqui.
}
```

saludos.

### EDICIÓN:

Mismo ejemplo que reproduce el problema que tienes (arreglada la parte de #someArea):

```js
$(function() {
  var cart = [{
    id: 1,
    Product: "Papa negra",
    Qty: 10,
    Price: 10.3
  }, {
    id: 2,
    Product: "Papa blanca",
    Qty: 5,
    Price: 15.9
  },{
    id: 3,
    Product: "Papa falsa",
    Qty: 5,
    Price: 3.9
  }];

  function deleteItem(index) {
    alert(index);
    //cart.splice(index, 1);
    //mostrar_carrito();
  }

  function mostrar_carrito() {
    $("#cart").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#cartBody").empty();

    for (var i in cart) {
      var item = cart[i];
      var row = "<tr><td>" + item.Product + "</td><td>" +
        item.Price + "</td><td>" + item.Qty + "</td><td>" +
        item.Qty * item.Price + "</td><td id='item" + item.id + "'/>";

      $("#cartBody").append(row);

      var button = document.createElement("button");
      button.innerHTML = "borrar";
      button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        deleteItem(i);
      });

      $("#item" + item.id).append(button);


    }
  }
  
  mostrar_carrito();
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cart">
  <table id="cartBody">
  </table>
</div>
```

y La Solución, usando el método de extraer la función:

```js
$(function() {
  var cart = [{
    id: 1,
    Product: "Papa negra",
    Qty: 10,
    Price: 10.3
  }, {
    id: 2,
    Product: "Papa blanca",
    Qty: 5,
    Price: 15.9
  }, {
    id: 3,
    Product: "Papa falsa",
    Qty: 5,
    Price: 3.9
  }];

  function deleteItem(index) {
    alert(index);
    //cart.splice(index, 1);
    //mostrar_carrito();
  }

  function mostrar_carrito() {
    $("#cart").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#cartBody").empty();

    for (var i in cart) {
      creaRegistro(cart[i], i);      
    }
    
    function creaRegistro(item, index) {
       var row = "<tr><td>" + item.Product + "</td><td>" +
  item.Price + "</td><td>" + item.Qty + "</td><td>" +
  item.Qty * item.Price + "</td><td id='item" + item.id + "'/>";

       $("#cartBody").append(row);

       var button = document.createElement("button");
       button.innerHTML = "borrar";
       button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  deleteItem(index);
       });

       $("#item" + item.id).append(button);
    }

  }

  mostrar_carrito();
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cart">
  <table id="cartBody">
  </table>
</div>
```

Otro ejemplo con let

```js
$(function() {
  var cart = [{
    id: 1,
    Product: "Papa negra",
    Qty: 10,
    Price: 10.3
  }, {
    id: 2,
    Product: "Papa blanca",
    Qty: 5,
    Price: 15.9
  },{
    id: 3,
    Product: "Papa falsa",
    Qty: 5,
    Price: 3.9
  }];

  function deleteItem(index) {
    alert(index);
    //cart.splice(index, 1);
    //mostrar_carrito();
  }

  function mostrar_carrito() {
    $("#cart").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#cartBody").empty();

    for (let i in cart) {
      var item = cart[i];
      var row = "<tr><td>" + item.Product + "</td><td>" +
        item.Price + "</td><td>" + item.Qty + "</td><td>" +
        item.Qty * item.Price + "</td><td id='item" + item.id + "'/>";

      $("#cartBody").append(row);

      var button = document.createElement("button");
      button.innerHTML = "borrar";
      button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        deleteItem(i);
      });

      $("#item" + item.id).append(button);


    }
  }
  
  mostrar_carrito();
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cart">
  <table id="cartBody">
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente!!! Claro, era iniciar la función mucho antes de lo que esperaba. GRACIAS. :)

Answer (score 1):

Con el código que compartes realicé una pequeña prueba en un JSFiddle que acá te comparto https://jsfiddle.net/jgvxnyae/1/ tal vez pueda echarle una mirada a este y ver si este es lo que buscas.

Encontré que en el código que compartes, el td llamado `someArea` se va a crear la cantidad de veces que existan en el arreglo y cuando agregas el botón a este contenido jQuery retorna el primero que encuentra y aquí agrega el botón, así que decidí modificar este id e incrementarlo por cada item que exista en el arreglo.

```js
$("#btnCarrito").on("click", function() {
  mostrar_carrito();
})

function mostrar_carrito() {

  $("#cart").css("visibility", "visible");
  $("#cartBody").empty();

  for (var i in cart) {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = i;
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
      deleteItem(i);
    });

    var item = cart[i];
    var row = "<tr><td>" + item.Nombre + "</td><td>" + item.Valor + "</td><td>" + item.Cantidad * item.Valor + "</td><td id='someArea" + i + "'></td></tr>"
    
    $("#cartBody").append(row);
    $("#someArea" + i).append(button);
  }
}

function deleteItem(index) {
  alert(index);
}

function objetoVenta(valor, nombre, cantidad) {
  this.Valor = valor;
  this.Nombre = nombre;
  this.Cantidad = cantidad;
}

var camisa = new objetoVenta(1000, "Camisa", 1);
var pantalon = new objetoVenta(2000, "Pantalón", 2);
var cart = [camisa, pantalon];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="btnCarrito" value="Mostrar Carrito" type="button" />
<table id="cart">
  <tbody id="cartBody">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Espero esto te ayude a encontrar la solución que necesitas.

Comment: Buena observación, no había llegado ahí, pero tienes razón. Sin embargo lo que busco en sí, es que al momento de borrar el producto con le addEventListener deleteItem(i); el parámetro que esta enviando no es el correcto. Siempre borra el último del bucle.

Comment: @GoInSu siempre borra el ultimo elemento por lo que te explique en mi respuesta. En javascript, a diferencia de muchos otros lenguajes, no puede hacerse una función en un blucle y apuntar la variable del bucle sin que pase esto. Saludos.,

Comment: Si el problema es lo que menciona @md entonces lo que se puede hacer es capturar la variable del bucle y enviarla en vez de la que hace parte del bucle. No se si una alternativa sea hacer un clón del objeto, con un poco más de código para conocer más el contexto se podría dar una mejor respuesta.

Comment: El problema en si, es que Chrome extensions no permite el uso de onclick(), por lo que se utiliza addEventListener. Si existiera una posibilidad con el atributo <a></a> para pasar la variable probablemente me evite todo este enrollo. ¿Alguien sabe de alguna forma?, NO doy con ninguna. Ya intente con la posiblidad de @rnd pero no puedo concretar ninguna opción.

Comment: @GoInSu hay otros errores en tu codigo ahora que lo intente ejecutar, los has corregido, el carro no se construye correctamente. Puedes acutlaizar a tu ultima version y te muestro como corregirlo?