# AddEvent Listener problema

Tags: html, css, web, eventos, frontend

Hice una funcion que toma todas las imagenes de mi pagina html
Y les agrega un evento de click que le cambia el estilo de negro que las oculta a ninguno

El problema es que al darle reload a la pagina lanza esta excepcion:
Script1.js:36  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')
at animacionMostrar (Script1.js:36:52)
at Script1.js:44:5
Que indica que hay algun problema con el addEventListener
Que puede ser?

Aqui esta el codig:

```
var animacionMostrar = function () {
   

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("img")[j].addEventListener("click", function() {
            if (document.getElementsByTagName("img")[j].style.filter == 'brightness(0)') {
                document.getElementsByTagName("img")[j].style.filter = 'none';
           }
       
        });
    }
}

animacionMostrar();
```

Comment: eso es porque al momento de cargar las imagenes no estan listas puedes solventar poniendo el codigo al final antes de cierre del body y agregando un listener asi  `window.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
     var animacionMostrar = function () { //resto de codigo }
});` o pasando de variable a  `function animacionMostrar(){}`  y llamandola dentro del onload.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [AddEventListener únicamente borra el ultimo valor del bucle con botones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21464/addeventlistener-%c3%banicamente-borra-el-ultimo-valor-del-bucle-con-botones)

Comment: por qué usas un ciclo y consultas una variable que no es la del ciclo 20 veces?

Answer (score 0):

Quiere decir que no existe `document.getElementsByTagName("img")[j]`

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img")[j].addEventListener
|__________________ __________________|
                   V
             Esto es undefined
```

Las 2 causas comunes para eso es que el selector sea incorrecto (que es dudoso en este caso particular) y la otra causa que es la más probable, es que tu código javascript se ejecute antes de que el DOM haya cargado completamente.

Para solventar este último problema puedes usar el evento [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
   document.querySelectorAll("img")
     .forEach(el=>{
        el.addEventListener("click", item => {
            if (item.style.filter == 'brightness(0)') 
                item.style.filter = 'none';
        })   
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Te está diciendo que no puede leer la propiedad `style` de `undefined`, o sea que no encuentra la enésima imágen.

Por otro lado, para que siquiera entre al handler que modifica el estilo, necesariamente Tene que heber declarado el `addEventListener` sobre ella, en un inicio.

Corolario: una o más imágenes ya no están en el DOM cuando se ejecuta el handler. Esto no sería problema si el handler sobre un cierto elemento ejecutara cambios sobre **ese** elemento, en tu caso sí es un problema.

En un flujo de ejemplo:

- Declaras un loop de N elementos
- La imagen A ocupa la décimo novena posición
- Se declara un eventListener sobre ella, que modifica el estilo de la décimo novena imagen
- Un subconjuto de los predecesores de A se eliminan del documento
- Se hace click en A (que ahora viene siendo el décimosexto elemento)
- El handler de A intenta modificar el décimonoveno elemento
- Todo explota

Solución: haz que cada imagen esté a cargo de sí misma

```
    const imgElement = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[j]

    imgElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (imgSlement.style.filter == 'brightness(0)') {
            imgElement.style.filter = 'none';
       }
    });
```

Que es muy distinto a declarar un handler sobre la imagen que inicialmente ocupa el lugar N, el cual al ejecutarse modifica la imagen que ocupe el lugar N en ese momento.

```
    document.getElementsByTagName("img")[j].addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (document.getElementsByTagName("img")[j].style.filter == 'brightness(0)') {
            document.getElementsByTagName("img")[j].style.filter = 'none';
       }
    });
```